# SMS notification on Bluetooth

Tags: notifications, sms, bluetooth

How can I get text notifications on my 390 Plantronics bluetooth device from my Galaxy Prevail 2 if it has that feature?
I have tried my settings in my phone but it only has the option for call audio.
What else can I do?

Comment: What kind of text notifications are you talking about? Message alert tone?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about *Audio* here (e.g. having notifications, alarms, etc. sent to your (Bluetooth) headset), you might wish to take a look at [SoundAbout](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.woodslink.android.wiredheadphoneroutingfix):

[image: SoundAbout Settings] [image: SoundAbout Settings]
<sup>*SoundAbout* settings screens (source: *Google Play*; click images for larger variants)</sup>

This app allows you to define which audio signal is routed where (even on certain conditions). I'm not sure how far the *free* version goes concerning Bluetooth, as the app description says *Bluetooth behavior - (Pro version)*. To my understanding, those "behavior settings" only include specifics like "force to mono", but I don't use the app myself, and thus cannot tell for sure.